# What are the six types of equanimity based on the household life?

Tags: pali-canon

I am reading [SN 36.22](https://suttacentral.net/sn36.22/en/bodhi), which says:

> And what, bhikkhus, are the thirty-six kinds of feelings? Six types of
>   joy based on the household life, six types of joy based on
>   renunciation; six types of displeasure based on the household life,
>   six types of displeasure based on renunciation; **six types of
>   equanimity based on the household life**, six types of equanimity based
>   on renunciation. These are called the thirty-six kinds of feelings.
>   “And what, bhikkhus, are the hundred and eight kinds of feelings? The
>   above thirty-six feelings in the past, the above thirty-six feelings
>   in the future, the above thirty-six feelings at present. These are
>   called the hundred and eight kinds of feelings.

What are the six types of equanimity based on the household life?

Comment: It's described in the Sutta: based on the six kinds of senses there are six kinds, in the case it's missed in the Sutta. But good that householder investigates this matter.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/25046/what-is-the-difference-between-householder-and-renunciation-equanimity?r=SearchResults

Comment: This thread contains the right answer for me. The "duplicate thread" does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> (E) Therein, what are the 6 kinds of equanimity of the household life (cha gehasitā upekkhā)?
>
> (25) On seeing a form with the eye, equanimity arises in a foolish, confused, worlding,
>   in an untutored worldling who has not conquered his limitations
>   nor conquered his karmic fruits, who sees not danger.
>   Such an equanimity as this does not transcend form.
>   Therefore, it is called the equanimity of the household life.
>
> (26) On hearing a sound with the ear, equanimity arises in a foolish, confused, worlding,
>   in an untutored worldling who has not conquered his limitations
>   nor conquered his karmic fruits, who sees not danger.
>   Such an equanimity as this does not transcend sound.
>   Therefore, it is called the equanimity of the household life.
>
> (27) On smelling a smell with the nose, equanimity arises in a foolish, confused, worlding,
>   in an untutored worldling who has not conquered his limitations
>   nor conquered his karmic fruits, who sees not danger.
>   Such an equanimity as this does not transcend smell.
>   Therefore, it is called the equanimity of the household life.
>
> (28) On tasting a taste with the tongue, equanimity arises in a foolish, confused, worlding,
>   in an untutored worldling who has not conquered his limitations
>   nor conquered his karmic fruits, who sees not danger.
>   Such an equanimity as this does not transcend taste.
>   Therefore, it is called the equanimity of the household life.
>
> (29) On feeling a touch with the body, equanimity arises in a foolish, confused, worlding,
>   in an untutored worldling who has not conquered his limitations
>   nor conquered his karmic fruits, who sees not danger.
>   Such an equanimity as this does not transcend touch.
>   Therefore, it is called the equanimity of the household life.
>
> (30) On cognizing a mind-object with the mind, equanimity arises in a foolish, confused, worlding,
>   in an untutored worldling who has not conquered his limitations
>   nor conquered his karmic fruits, who sees not danger.
>   Such an equanimity as this does not transcend mind-object.
>   Therefore, it is called the equanimity of the household life.
>
> These are the 6 kinds of equanimity of the household life.

[Sal,āyatana Vibhanga Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/29.5-Salayatana-Vibhanga-S-m137-piya.pdf)

> (1) the latent tendency to lust reinforced by being attached to pleasant feelings;
>
> (2) the latent tendency to aversion reinforced by rejecting painful feelings;
>
> (3) the latent tendency to ignorance reinforced by ignoring neutral feelings

[Pahāna Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/31.1-Pahana-S-s36.3-piya.pdf)

So the neutral feeling or equanimous feeling experienced, in the case of a householder leads to ignorance. The equanimity, in this case, is not been non-judgemental.

Comment: `So the neutral feeling in the case of a householder leads to ignorance.` yes, but also for a recluse if not really renounced the world.